# Blender weird error

Tags: error

So recently in blender I've been getting this message anytime I use this s3py plugin to import an object to make poses for the sims 3 game. I know you might tell me to contact the creator of the plugin but they are no longer active anymore. Does anyone know what this error might mean? This randomly starting happening. I tried deleting the plugin and reinstalling it, but I get the same message. I tried to downgrade my blender  version since it was made for 2.67b (I'm currently running 2.79c) but my computer isn't compatible with it anymore (well it won't open anymore.) Again everything used to work fine and I've been running it on 2.79c for a while now, this is just something new [image]

Comment: From where did you get the "2.79c"? There have never been such release

Comment: You are trying to install an old addon with a new Blender & Python version. Either use the old Blender & Python version, or contact the authors requesting an update of their addon.

Answer (score 3):

The error happens because `shutil.abspath(path)` was deprecated [in 2014](https://bugs.python.org/issue21391). [`os.path.abspath(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) should be used instead. The script was apparently written for an older version of python that still included that function in `shutil`, which matches your description that the add-on was developed for Blender 2.67.

Comment: thanks for letting me know! its weird that it would be happening now since I've been using the plugin with blender 2.79 for quite a while now. Would there be a way for me to somehow edit the script to make it compatible with my version

Comment: @AGTvSeries you can edit the script, however there may be more to update than just that line. Perhaps this bug was in a code branch that wasn't usually executed?